# Generating all set of permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm

Recently in an interview, I was asked the following question:

> Given a list of pairs of numbers, like `(2, 6)(4, 5)(1, 5)`, generate all numbers of the form `241,242,243,244,245,251...`.  Note that the length of list of pairs is variable, i.e., we could have more than 3 pairs of numbers.  Each pair represents an "inclusive interval".  Each of the numbers generated, for e.g., `241` should come from each of the intervals: `2` from the first, `4` from the second, `1` from the third and so on.  Duplicates are not to be treated any specially, i.e., `555` is valid and should be part of the output sequence.

I came up with the simple brute force logic:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> res;

void helper(pair<int,int>& interval) {
  int start=interval.first;
  int end=interval.second;
  vector<int> ans;
  
  for(int i=0; i<res.size(); i++) {
    for(int j=start; j<=end; j++) {
      ans.push_back(res[i]*10+j);
    }
  }
  
  res=ans;
}

vector<int> generatePermutation(vector<pair<int,int>>& intervals) {
  if(intervals.empty()) return res;
  
  pair<int, int> firstInt=intervals[0];
  for(int i=firstInt.first; i<=firstInt.second; i++) {
    res.push_back(i);
  }
 
  for(int i=1; i<intervals.size(); i++) { 
    helper(intervals[i]);
  }
  
  return res;
}


int main() {
    vector<pair<int,int>> v;
    v.push_back({2,6});
    v.push_back({4,5});
    v.push_back({1,5});

    vector<int> ans=generatePermutation(v);
    
    for(auto& each: ans) cout<<each<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

Which generates the answer [as needed](https://ideone.com/vJjSjX).  But I was curious to know if there is some efficient algorithm to this problem?  The interviewer did not have any time complexity on mind, although he said he was looking for a recursive solution making me think if we could perhaps solve it by backtracking in a more efficient manner.

Comment: Can you explain me more about the test case which you have showed in the post? How 
`241,242,243,244,245,251...` are made from `(2, 6)(4, 5)(1, 5)`?

Comment: @electricalapprentice, first 2 from the first pair, 4 form the second and each from the last (third pair); then first 2 from the first pair, 5 from the second and each from the last (third pair) and so on.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think you can get better than brute force if you need to generate all numbers - you need to pass by each of them after all, and that's `O(n^k)`. Although I can't provide any rigorous proof for that.

Comment: The shown algorithm seems to be fundamentally flawed. Based on the description of the problem, every number pair should be handled equivalently but the shown code, for some reason, treats the first pair in some special way, using it to generate the contents of a global object (which would be a demerit on its own, anyway), then use it in some unclear fashion with all remaining pair of numbers get handled in a completely different way. This does not look right. The issue here is not efficiency, but using the right algorithm. Sorry to say, but I think you've blown this interview question.

Comment: ... and the global object also gets overwritten? This seems to be quite wrong.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, any pointers to better (and perhaps efficient) code please?

Comment: Either I don’t understand how 242 is made or the fact that they are in pairs is completely irrelevant to the question at hand

Comment: @Taekahn, in `242`, the first `2` comes from the first pair `(2,6)`, middle `4` comes from the second pair `(4,5)`, while the last `2` comes from the last (third) pair `(1,5)` when it is expanded.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It's very unlikely that "any pointers to better ... code" exist anywhere. This is for the simple reason is that it wouldn't make much sense to ask interview questions if their answers are widely available on the intertubes. The whole point of asking interview questions, like this, is to ask something that's uncommon, and require the understanding of algorithms and computer science fundamentals; rather than rote memorization, and cribbing the results of a Google search. This is trying to test if the job candidate knows how to figure out correct logic, and not run a Google search.

Comment: @Someone no. That just raises more questions. Where/what is this “expansion”? Is every pair supposed to represent a number range? Inclusive or exclusive? Do the numbers generated have to come from only one range each or are they all allowed to pull from each range? If so, how are duplicates supposed to be handled.

Comment: @Taekahn, yes, every pair represents a number range, inclusive.  Each digit should come from a different range, i.e., each digit of `242` comes from 1st, 2nd and 3rd set respectively.  Duplicates are not treated specially, i.e., `555` is valid and should be output.  If you refer this [ideone link](https://ideone.com/vJjSjX), you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Someone I think I finally got the meaning of the test case :D.

Comment: Yeah, a recursive function is pretty much the only practical solution here. If an attempt is made to compile and run the shown code, with some test input, the results will be wrong. Working this out in my head, the recursive function should be about eight lines of code, and a 2nd function, to start the recursion (like the shown code tries to do), would be three lines of code. No global objects. That's it. The stated problem's purpose is to test knowledge and understanding of recursion, containers, iterators, algorithms, and basic math.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, could you please post your code?  Please feel free to post it as an answer or pastebin, etc. (if you think it is not an answer, per se).  Thanks in anticipation.  I am specifically interested in seeing how you handle the case where `intervals.size()==1`.  IMO we need a special case to handle the first expansion.

Comment: Haven’t rigorously thought it through but my first thought, then, would be to figure out the lowest possible number, figure out the highest possible number, and then print all in between. I guess you would would probably need  a quick if check to decide to print or not, but that wouldn’t be too hard

Comment: @Taekahn, what do you mean?  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Please rephrase the question with the very key information from the comments. This has nothing to do with permutations; the example is confusing (to at least 3 people before me), too short, and not explained; you say 'pairs' of numbers with no reference to the very crucial fact that they represent inclusive intervals of whole numbers, etc...

Comment: No, you don't need a special case "where intervals.size()==1", but when it's 0, an empty set.

Comment: @kcsquared, thank you for your input; I have edited the question and included the details.

Comment: That's a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), not a permutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only practical solution here is the one your interviewer hinted at you: recursion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void genperms(std::vector<int> &res, int n,
          std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>::const_iterator b,
          std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>::const_iterator e)
{
    if (b == e)
    {
        res.push_back(n);
        return;
    }

    n *= 10;

    for (int i=b->first; i <= b->second; ++i)
        genperms(res, n+i, b+1, e);
}

std::vector<int> genperms(const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &pairs)
{
    std::vector<int> res;

    if (!pairs.empty())
        genperms(res, 0, pairs.begin(), pairs.end());

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    auto res=genperms({{2,6}, {4, 5}, {1, 5}});

    for (auto n:res)
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Resulting output (truncated for brevity):

```
241
242
243
244
245
251
252

(snippola)

652
653
654
655
```